# Evaluating an integral with implicit function as lower bound

Tags: matlab

I have this function:

```
 psi = @(x,y)(-(11*x^(6/5)*y^(1/5) - 19*x + 9)/(10*x^(1/10)*y^(1/10)))
```

Solving for x can only be done implicitly:

```
 R_sp = @(y)solve(psi(x,y), x);
```

I need to evaluate the following double integral with R_sp as the lower bound:

```
 int(s * int(s*t, t, R_sp(s), 1), s, .3, .4)
```

When evaluating, matlab says: Error in MuPAD command: A list or a table of entries is expected. [(Dom::Matrix(Dom::ExpressionField()))::create]

The values of R_sp are well-defined in [.3, .4] and can be calculated easily:

```
R_sp(.3) = 0.845993307852830503940553192774
R_sp(.4) = 0.89641082924669996315283636152907
```

So I assume that the int function of matlab cannot process continuous values in that implicit function, right? Of course in this case, I can use the trapz function to approximate the integral above by calculating discrete value pairs of the integrand in a for-loop. But is there any other way in matlab to evaluate this integral other than using the trapz approximation (using continuous values)?